# Why do you allow moderators to hold/close questions they cannot answer?

Tags: discussion

What is the point of having a question and answer forum if people cannot ask questions without them being frozen for no good reason by contributors clearly gaming the system rather than actually addressing the question.  In this "too broad" is meaningless nonsense that really means the moderator doesn't understand the question.  Off Topic when it clearly on-topic for salesforce.

You really need to do something about abuse of power and/or gaming the system to the detriment of other users.

Here are three questions by the same moderator that are far broader, far more opinion based or just plain off topic.

[(Why) Should I Use Lightning Apps?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67690/why-should-i-use-lightning-apps)

[Why Are Data Silos Important in Unit Tests?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122445/why-are-data-silos-important-in-unit-tests)

[Pokemon Catch - Generic Exception Handling In Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136920/pokemon-catch-generic-exception-handling-in-apex)

Comment: Martin, I want to say that I understand and appreciate your frustration with your SFSE experience so far, and acknowledge that the mechanics and boundaries of Stack Exchange aren't always as clear as they could be. That said, I don't appreciate the tone and accusations here. If you'd like to have a discussion on Meta about the boundaries of on-topicness or about why a specific question was closed, I for one am happy to participate and provide support. Rants and ad-hominem language are not productive and do not lead to conversation that can move us forward as a community.

Comment: If you'd like to revise your question to be *factual* ("why is this question off-topic?"), I'd be happy to engage further. In its current state, I believe it merits removal based on the Stack Exchange [Code of Conduct](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: I've toned down the language as requested, however the core point still holds, that closing that question is a very clear abuse of power, IMHO.  It is about SF, it is far more limited in scope than closer's own questions.  He has also very clear broken the four expectations heading up that code of conduct.  Frankly I not bothered what you do with him, as long as my question is opened up to answers otherwise I'm just wasting my time.

Comment: Making personal attacks against other users on this site is never appropriate, and you didn't even link to [your own post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/264195/2995) for reference. I closed your post because there are a wide range of ways to solve your problem, and it is a design question so which is best has no objective basis. If you would like to state your case for it being on topic, that would be one thing. But your post as written is still quite derogatory and could be legitimately flagged as rude/abusive.

Comment: So @AdrianLarson you think reporting what I consider is abuse of power is inappropriate?  That say more about you than it does me. That you expect to do as you please without having to account for your actions.  You think the question is too broad, but you cannot provide a single answer?  If you really think it is too broad then ignore it and move on and let somebody else answer it.  Providing answers is after all supposed to be the point of this site.  If it cannot provide answers then what is the point of posting questions?  There is none.

Comment: The fact that a reasonable complaint has been downvoted twice is pretty toxic example of how stifling this place has become.

Comment: Forget it, I can't be bothered any more, unreasonable behaviour has hounded out a newbie I hope you are proud of yourself , you delete my account as per the requirements of the GDPR.

Answer (score 5):

The number of questions I vote to close has dropped significantly since I became a moderator. I now try to only close the most obviously off topic questions, and generally let the community at large handle close votes. Please remember that this is a volunteer position, and we are all trying our best.

I stand by my closing of your [most recent question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/264195/2995).

## How you could fix the original question

As written, your post is a solicitation for design ideas. This makes it both opinion based (judging which is best is purely subjective), as well as quite broad (there are nearly infinite possible solutions). I closed it for the latter reason, but the former would certainly be appropriate as well.

The format for this site is *specific* questions and answers. You did a good job including what you have tried so far, but asking how to make some UI attractive/responsive is not on topic, and is instead likely to lead to significant back-and-forth. If you wanted to ask something along the lines of how you could convert this menu structure to [use SLDS](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/menus/), that could well be on topic. That is specific enough that one could post a clear answer and be confident it is correct, would help you, and would be useful for others in the coming years.

## How you could fix this Meta post

Your original wording contained rude/abusive language, and your edit did remove some of that problem. However, your post still contains much content which is not fact based, assumes the worst, and adds nothing to a discussion whose end goal is to actually resolve any problem.

- Stating the closure is "meaningless" is not productive.

  - It would be better to instead ask why the post was closed, or what changes could be made to get it reopened.
- Stating that "the moderator doesn't understand the question" is an (incorrect) assumption and throws unnecessary shade.
- Ordering "You really need to do something"  doesn't fit with the general approach on Meta, where we try to seek consensus about the best path forward.
- Implying some sort of "abuse of power and/or gaming the system" is a bit nonsensical and again assumes the worst.

  - *We are volunteers*
  - We signed up to be moderators because we get a lot of value out of this community and want to keep it great.
  - There is no system to game, I obtain no specific personal benefit from closing posts, other than looking out for the overall health of the exchange.
  - I try to be as careful as possible about using these privileges.
- Pointing out specific questions and stating that they are "far broader, far more opinion based or just plain off topic" makes no attempt to move forward and resolve your situation, nor to understand the reasoning behind the system.

## Why are those posts on-topic?

Each of the questions you linked to are/were relevant to a large number of developers. Aside from the exception handling post, your coloring of my questions as broad or opinion based is not correct.

**(Why) Should I Use Lightning Apps?**

In 2015, the lightning platform was not very mature, and despite its rollout and buzzword status, did not feel like the right tool for the job in most UI applications. The question boiled down to something very specific and objectively answerable:

> What do Lightning Applications do better than VisualForce Pages? What types of problems are they worse at handling?

Ultimately, it was more about can/cannot than better/worse, but it was possible to answer concisely and objectively.

**Why Are Data Silos Important in Unit Tests?**

I found a shortcoming in the official documentation, and asked a specific question which can be addressed with objective arguments.

> Why is it important to create our own data when we write unit tests?

Yes, it is somewhat broad, in that you could probably write entire dissertations on the topic. But as the answers demonstrated, it is possible to write a concise, relatively complete, high quality answer. Each of the other users who posted an answer there could be reasonably confident they had addressed my question in a satisfactory manner which would not require dozens of follow up questions.

**Pokemon Catch - Generic Exception Handling In Apex**

There was some back and forth on this one, and it is certainly true that you could close it for many of the same reasons. It comes back around to how widely applicable the question is. We strongly advise against something in our best practice guidelines, but at that time did not have a clear, concrete justification for why. So I asked a very specific question which can be addressed via objective arguments, measurements, and facts:

> Is it ever acceptable (or even preferable) to catch a generic Exception in Apex? Are there repercussions to watch out for?

Is it opinion based? Yes, it is. But the key reasons it was reopened and remains open is that this question can be addressed via objective arguments and it is very broadly applicable (it affects most developers on a week in, week out basis).

## How I handled a similar situation

If you read through the comments on that last post you mention, you may notice:

> This question was reopend based on community votes and a topic in our [meta](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/is-it-really-opinion-based-though).

This question was closed, and I also brought it up on Meta. And while it's true that I do call someone out specifically, the only subjective/negative thing I say about them is that they are *clearly disgruntled*. That is a far cry short of saying someone is *power crazy*, or that they are *gaming* or *abusing the system*,  or that they *don't understand the question*. Those are character judgments which quite frankly feel hurtful and unfair.

Outside of my one subjective observation, I stated *facts* about what happened, explained why *I thought the flag was incorrect*, then *asked the community* if they agreed.

Comment: "To Broad" is meaningless because it is entirely based on your opinion, it is also not in the slightest helpful.  It is interesting that you feel your opinions are fine but mine are not.  The conclusions in my post are entirely reasonable given the evidence.  Claiming you are gaming the system is laughable.  Closing the question is gaming the system, down voting this question is gaming the system, upvoting your own comments is gaming the system.

Comment: ... and limiting my responses to comments that disappear because they are too long

Comment: I'm not sure why you think I am limiting any of your responses. I am trying to engage in civil discussion about how this site works and offering constructive ways you can get more out of the community. I don't make any assumptions about what your motivations are, I only state facts. Calling your post a "solicitation for design ideas" is fact, and it does not make any character judgments. Your claim that I am up voting my own comments is also completely without merit. If you actually read what I write and engage in conversation, it would be fairly easy to resolve this issue.

Comment: Instead of trying to engage in a productive manner, you seem to prefer making baseless accusations and character judgments. Your interactions here display no attempt to understand how this community works or what you can do to use it effectively. Could I be wrong about this vote to close? Certainly. I don't think so, but I'm only human, and only one member of this website. That said, your combative approach has not helped your cause.